# C MACRO expansion dynamically

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

I am trying something similar to following in a legacy code

//Defining MACRO for PLATFORM 1

```
#define PLATFORM_1_ENTRY_L2PT    10
#define PLATFORM_1_ENTRY_L3PT    11
#define PLATFORM_1_ENTRY_L4PT    12
#define PLATFORM_1_ENTRY_L5PT    13
```

//Defining MACRO for PLATFORM 2

```
#define PLATFORM_2_ENTRY_L2PT    20
#define PLATFORM_2_ENTRY_L3PT    21
#define PLATFORM_2_ENTRY_L4PT    22
#define PLATFORM_2_ENTRY_L5PT    23
```

//DEFINING MACRO for default platform

```
#define DEFAULT_PLATFORM_ENTRY_L2PT    30
#define DEFAULT_PLATFORM_ENTRY_L3PT    31
#define DEFAULT_PLATFORM_ENTRY_L4PT    32
#define DEFAULT_PLATFORM_ENTRY_L5PT    33
```

//GETTING offset based on 'dynamic' platform TYPE

```
#define GET_OFFSET(entry_type)   ({                                          \
     (global.platform_1) ?                                                   \
         PLATFORM_1_ENTRY_##entry_type :                                     \
         (global.platform_2) ?                                               \
              PLATFORM_2_ENTRY_##entry_type :                                \
              DEFAULT_PLATFORM_ENTRY_##entry_type)                           \
     })
```

//Using the following macro expansion to expand based on platform type

```
#define ENTRY_L2PT                                       GET_OFFSET(L2PT)
#define ENTRY_L3PT                                       GET_OFFSET(L3PT)
#define ENTRY_L4PT                                       GET_OFFSET(L4PT)
#define ENTRY_L5PT                                       GET_OFFSET(L5PT)
```

//Defining the global structure

```
struct global_ {
    bool platform_1;
    bool platform_2;
} glbl;

glbl global = {0};
```

//calling from sample main

```
void main() {
    //set offset 
    int array[40] = {0};
    ...
    if(sizeof (void *) * CHARBIT == 64) {
        global.platform_1 = 1;
    } else {
        global.platform_2 = 1;
    }
    array[ENTRY_L2PT]++;
    array[ENTRY_L3PT]++;
    array[ENTRY_L4PT]++;
    array[ENTRY_L5PT]++;
    ...
}
```

** I am getting Getting following error during compilation:**

```
At top level:
error: braced-group within expression allowed only inside a function
#define GET_OFFSET(entry_type)   ({                                        \
                                  ^
note: in expansion of macro ‘GET_OFFSET’
#define ENTRY_L2PT                GET_OFFSET(L2PT)
                                             ^
note: in expansion of macro ‘ENTRY_L2PT’
        array[ENTRY_L2PT]++;
```

how do I make the above work?

Please note that there are multiple places where ENTRY_L2PT is used in code, and replacing all of them has a lot of effort in development/testing/regression etc.

Comment: After fixing several typos and adding missing headers, I'm getting a completely different error (`expected ';' before ')' token`) pointing at the final typo: `##entry_type)`, which should be replaced with `##entry_type;`. If this doesn't help, please provide a [mcve] that we can compile and see the same error as you.

Comment: Unless all those macros always exist, you cannot use a solution like this, because all of `PLATFORM_1_ENTRY_##entry_type`, `PLATFORM_2_ENTRY_##entry_type` and so on will always get expanded. Are they always present?

Comment: yes, PLATFORM_1_ENTRY_##entry_type, PLATFORM_2_ENTRY_##entry_type etc always exist.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you are using? Don't you get `CHARBIT` is undefiend, and `struct` is missing a typedef, and don't you get ``expected ';' before ')' token` error? Are you sure you are using the code you posted?

Answer (score 0):

> how do I make the above work?
>
> braced-group within expression allowed only inside a function

Don't use a braced-group.

```
#define GET_OFFSET(entry_type)   ( \
     .... \
     .... \
     )
```